# Explain Octal and the linux command od + understanding 0x00

Tags: linux, bash, command, octal

I'm trying to understand what this linux command does

```
ls | od -c
```

I know it's sending **ls** to **od -c**.

But what is **od -c**? What is a Octal and how is this useful?

This next question isn't relevant, but..
Since I'm at it, what's **0x00** , **0x01**, **0x02**....etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`od -c` dumps C-style escaped characters, `man od` is your friend

`0x00` is hexadecimal number 00 (`0x` in C and many others indicate hex number)